# Regular expression to check phone number contains 10 zeroes in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

I have a regular expression to check phone number.It returns 'true' for 10 zeroes. How to change regular expression to return 'false' for 10 zeroes. Following is my code

```
var phoneno = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;

phoneno.test('8129587912');// returns true .Works good

phoneno.test('asdff');// returns false .Works good

phoneno.test('0000000000');//returns true. Not Working As Expected
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: How does `phoneno.test('asdff')` match fine? What is your objective here? It's a bit confusing. You want to allow phone numbers but not one that contains 10 zeroes?

Comment: [7-9][0-9]{9}$ this may help you..

Comment: @degantSorry for the mis-leading comment in the code.I have edited my question.

Comment: You can use this  ^[789]\d{9}$  regex for validating Indian mobile number

Comment: Why aren't you using one of the many tried and tested regexes for phone number validation?

Comment: @NitinDhomse I cannot restrict the phone numbers to 'Indian phone numbers'.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Can you suggest one of them for me?.

Comment: Sure.  https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Comment: `I cannot restrict the phone numbers to 'Indian phone numbers'.` - well, why are you restricting the test to 10 digits? that's an arbitrary number of digits in the first place

Comment: @JaromandaX I am new to regex. I got this regex from stack overflow .I just used it.Thats all.

Comment: @RahulKR - your question specifically asks about 10 digit phone number - I'm sorry I can't guess that you actually didn't write that code in the first place, so your issue is that you don't understand *RegEx101*

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes.I tried some tutorials but it was hard to follow those as a beginner.Can you suggest one for beginner?

Comment: no, because I find google search finds these sort of tutorials for you, and you can even select what (spoken) language the tutorial is in if you search for yourself

Comment: @JaromandaX OK , Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

This is what you asked for:

```
var phoneno = /^(?!0000000000)\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
```

Comment: It does exactly what he asked.  Nothing more, nothing less.  It's a bad implementation, but it is what he asked for.

Comment: Yea just a mess.

Answer (score 0):

If just want exclude 10 zeros circumstance, you can make a special case for that:

```
if( !/0{10}/.test(phonenum) ){
    //another rules...
}
```